# How to fetch value from Json Object inside objects in Android

Tags: android, json

I have some problem in fetching json value from the URl (http://fusioniprojects.com/ios/counter.php)

{ "ios": { "counter": "2" } }

I just want to fetch counter value
Thank you.

Comment: what programming language? what platform? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have grabbed the JSON from the URI and created a String from it....

You would create a JSONObject that contains the JSON:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
```

And then create JSONObjects where needed from there:

```
JSONObject iOSObject = jObject.getJSONObject("ios");
```

And finally, the value required, in this case, a String:

```
String theCounter = iOSObject.getString("counter");
```

so, without the comments:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;    

String yourJSONString = (import JSON here)... ;
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(yourJSONString);
JSONObject iOSObject = jObject.getJSONObject("iOS");
String theCounter = iOSObject.getString("counter");
```

Grabbing the JSON and turning it into a String to use is a little more complex, but I'm not entirely sure that's what you are after, the question is a little ambiguous.

Comment: It's a pleasure. If it helped any chance you could mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this, parse the json in js object and now you can access the counter property as follows

```
var a = '{ "ios": { "counter": "2" } }';

a = JSON.parse(a);

console.log(a['ios'].counter);
```